# When standardizing data, does that imply that the mean and standard deviation will become 0, respectively 1?

Tags: statistics, pca

As title suggests, I've been wondering about how standardization works when trying to understand how Principal Component Analysis( PCA) works from this tutorial https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/understanding-principle-component-analysis-pca-step-by-step-e7a4bb4031d9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES**

You can prove this by using properties of the mean and variance of a transformation, but the intuition is that subtracting the observed mean gives you a a new mean of zero (centers your data) and the dividing by the standard deviation compresses or expands the distribution to give a standard deviation of one.

Note that there is no requirement to standardize your data before you run PCA.

Comment: Understood. Regarding the centering of data, how can I tell if I need to centralize it or not? Depending on how spread out the data is or are there other aspects to consider?

Comment: That’s a good topic to ask about in a new question. (Remember that Data Science, like most or all of the other Stacks, is strictly Q&A, not a discussion forum. It works best when each question has its own post, so that people with the same question in the future have a question where they can find an answer,  rather than looking through discussions about related topics until they find the information they need.)